# Mongodb 2.6 index error - “key too large to index”

Tags: mongodb, text, indexing

We’ve started to use `Mongodb version 2.6`. When we try to create a text index, we have been facing an error occur which is

> Error :“key too large to index”.

We did some search and we found:  `Starting from version 2.6, MongoDB will not create an index if the value of existing index field exceeds the index key limit.` [MongoDB - Indexing Limitations](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_indexing_limitations.htm)

We need to create an index on the textual content of every web page in a web site.

- How can we create text index with Mongodb version 2.6?
- Should we go back the previous version?

Comment: Do you really want an index on the entire page content (as opposed for example to a full text index) ?

Comment: mongoDB puts the restriction on the index size because indexes are stored in RAM and if total size of indexes exceed RAM size then you will face performance issues. So, try to minimize size of your index or put some encryption logic on your page content and then save it as index

Comment: @codiacTushki That is a fair point that should be taken seriously by OP.

Comment: @FrederickCheung yes, we need to create index on the entire content ("Full text index" is named "Text index" in mongodb)

Comment: And you're creating a text index as described in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/ ?

Comment: @FrederickCheung yes exactly

Comment: I dont think it will fix your problem, but if you're only just starting using MongoDB why not use the latest version (3)?  Is there a reason you've started with an old version?

Answer (score 1):

This is a size limitation set by default in Mongo 2.6. Try starting your `mongod` process with this parameter:

```
sudo mongod --setParameter failIndexKeyTooLong=false
```

[According to the documentation](http://docs.mongolab.com/errors/) the key index size is limited to 1024 bytes. But overriding this with the above parameter should help you out.

Comment: Thanks your advice. We tried it, but it didn't work. 

When we start indexing with your parameter, the entire text was skipped without indexing